# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_feed_input_names' in Keras Theano

Tags: python, keras, theano

While executing the statement,

```
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch,
               verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
I'm getting the error,
 File "C:\Users\Parag\Anaconda3\envs\keras_theano\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 737, in _standardize_user_data
    feed_input_names = self._feed_input_names
```

> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute
>   '_feed_input_names'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `input_shape` argument to the first layer in your network. This solved the issue for me.