# Keras: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_feed_input_names'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to create a multi-label classificator using Keras. The training data has the following format:

**X_train**

```
f1  f2  f3
1   1   5
0   2   4
1   0   4
```

**y_train:**

```
c1  c2
0   1
1   1
0   0
```

This is the code that I use to build the model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import math

def softmax(z):
    z_exp = [math.exp(i) for i in z]
    sum_z_exp = sum(z_exp)
    return [i / sum_z_exp for i in z_exp]

nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Dense(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(10,)))
nn.add(Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))

nn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

n = 10000
model.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values, batch_size=16, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

When I run this code, it fails with the message:

> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_feed_input_names'

Comment: A few hints, use `activation='softmax'` instead of using your custom softmax. That's because you are not using Keras symbolic tensors in that function. But since this code doesn't seem to use this activation, the problem is likely to be in `X_train.values` and `Y_train.values`. Make sure they both are numpy arrays with `print(type(X_train.values))`.

Answer (score 1):

I' m writing my suggestions here because i can't comment yet.
I think your input_shape might be off. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758374/attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute-feed-input-names?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062447/attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute-feed-input-names-in-kera) that someone other had the same problem. Maybe try something like:

```
nn.add(Dense(.... input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
```

I hope this helps :)